# How to make a button go through all the background colors

Tags: c#, loops, colors

```
foreach (Color b in new ColorConverter().GetStandardValues())
{
    button1.BackColor = b;
    Thread.Sleep(200);
}
```

Greetings,

Can someone explain, why this doesn't make my button's background color flash through all the known colors, instead it just changes to the last in line(Yellow Green). I want it to go through all the colors.

Comment: Don't freeze the UI thread.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread t1=new Thread(new ThreadStart(setColours));
    t1.Start();
}

private void setColours()
{
    foreach (Color b in new ColorConverter().GetStandardValues())
    {
        button1.BackColor = b;
        Thread.Sleep(200);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use "Invoke", or better still "BeginInvoke" to avoid some very odd deadlock situations sometimes

Comment: @Sudhakar It won't work; you'll get an exception for trying to manipulate a UI control from a background thread.  Even if you don't get an exception, it's still an unsafe operation to perform.

Comment: @Servy: Thanks for your valuable input, I have posted this answer as i it was working fine without any exceptions any how i will take care of that unsafe operation. Thankyou. so shall i use BeginInvoke here?

Answer (score 1):

You're blocking the UI thread for the entire duration of that loop, which prevents any other UI actions (such as re-drawing that button) from being executed.

What you can do is make the code asynchronous, such that you set the color and then don't do anything at all for some period of time and leave the UI thread free to do whatever it wants in the meantime.  C# 5.0 makes this *much* easier than older versions using the `await` keyword:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    foreach (Color b in new ColorConverter().GetStandardValues())
    {
        button1.BackColor = b;
        await Task.Delay(200);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thread-safe UI updating as per the comments on the accepted answer:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(setColours));
    t1.IsBackground = true;
    t1.Start();
}

private void setColours()
{
    foreach (Color b in new ColorConverter().GetStandardValues())
    {
        setColor(b);

        Thread.Sleep(200);
    }
}

delegate void setColorDelegate(Color b);

private void setColor(Color b)
{
    if (IsDisposed)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        Invoke(new setColorDelegate(setColor), b);
    }
    else
    {
        button1.BackColor = b;
    }
}
```